# Unity, Player isnt following along the waypoints

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, movement, waypoints

I have a player with a Rigidbody, I want it to follow along the Waypoints, I have a script for it I tested it first on a Cube, everything worked fine, but on my character it just moves Towards the first waypoint then stays on the first waypoint instead of going ahead. Even if I comment out the LookAt Code section its not working. It could maybe cause the Y position of the waypoints that my player is stuttering, I changed it now. It is now moving along but stuttering much.

Here is a picture of the problem:
[image: Picture of the problem]
[image: Picture of the problem1]

Here is my code:

---

```
public GameObject[] waypoints;

public float grindSpeed;
public float turnSpeed;

public int currentWaypoint;

private Animator anim;
private Rigidbody rb;

public bool isGrinding = false;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}


void Update()
{
    MoveAlongWaypoints();

    if(isGrinding)
        anim.SetBool ("isOnGrinding", true);
    else if(!isGrinding)
        anim.SetBool("isOnGrinding", false);
}

void MoveAlongWaypoints()
{
    if(isGrinding)
    {
        //TRANSLATE
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position, grindSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        //ROTATE
        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(transform.position == waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position)
        {
            currentWaypoint++;
        }
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "GrindWayPoint")
    {
        Debug.Log ("Waypoint!!");
        isGrinding = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful when mixing Rigidbody physics with direct transformation overrides. This rips control of the object's movement away from the physics engine, and can cause judder, weird collision behaviours, and even hamper performance (since the physics engine has to deal with out-of-band changes that are effectively teleports every time you move something without it). If you have a Rigidbody, route your movement through that, with velocity, AddForce, MovePosition, etc.

Comment: I know but how I move the player along the waypoints with AddForce or MovePosition? Never did this before like that.

Comment: That sounds like something worth posting as a Question. ;)

Comment: I concur with DM...if you are using the physics engine then move via forces. That's what it was made for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position is made up of floats. Most likely the 2 values in this check never equal each other because of roundoff errors:

`// These will probably never equal each other
if(transform.position == waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position)`

When comparing floats you need to set some tolerance range to do the comparison and call it "good enough". e.g.

`if((Math.Abs(transform.position.x - waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position.x) < 0.01)
&& (Math.Abs(transform.position.y - waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position.y) < 0.01)
&& (Math.Abs(transform.position.z - waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position.z) < 0.01))
{
   //close enough...assume they are equal...so do some stuff
   currentWaypoint++;
}`

Comment: You are right, what I tried would never equal, I changed now some code but I get an error when I try moving with rb.MovePosition. I get MoveTowards takes "2" Arguments, I tried converting MoveTowards to MovePosition but seems not to work.

//ADDFORCE
   Vector3 movePosition = transform.position;
   movePosition = Mathf.MoveTowards(transform.position + waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position * grindSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
   rb.MovePosition(movePosition);

Comment: Use: Vector3 moveDir = Vector3.Normalize(waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position - transform.position); rb.AddForce(DRIVING_FORCE*moveDir);  Where DRIVING_FORCE can be hard-coded or calculated frame-by-frame to be more realistic. Start with hard-coding. NOTE: You'll need to do this calculation and call AddForce every frame because forces are zeroed on each update.